# How to add column events in bootstrap table in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-table

I am trying to create a table like this:
' https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#column-options/events.html '
in Vue.
I could do this in Jquery, but I am not able to create those 'like' and 'delete' buttons with **Vue**. In my case I would like to add '*edit*' and '*delete*' buttons.I cannot find any documentation regarding this.
Also I am directly passing the data (array of objects) from the post request.

I don't think I should edit the array to add buttons html in each object.
I tried calling a function on the events option, just like the Jquery version, didn't work.

```
options: {
      search: true,
      sortable:true,
      searchAlign: 'right',
      pagination: true,
      searchAlign:'left',
      **events**: '????' //how do i do this
}
```

I expect to add a column along with my data in the table containing buttons for '*edit*' and '*delete*'.

Comment: `v-on="options.onDelete"`, `options.onDelete="{click: ..., mouseout:...,...}"`

Comment: @Estradiaz Please elaborate, I was able to create the buttons, but they dont work...
Basically, in this example https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#column-options/events.html#view-source I was able to create operateFormatter method in vue, but cannot call the operateEvents method.How can I do it in Vue.js?

Comment: is there a reason you are not using https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table ?

Comment: No, I will use this now, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Estradiaz Turns out there is no searching functionality in bootstrap-vue.
What do you recommend for dynamic searching?

Comment: Vue + JavaScript  kinda has, due to reactivity